# How to create jar file from Android Library project

Tags: java, android, jar

I have a Android library project need to convert this in to a jar file and use it on my Android project.like we are doing on Adds network integrations,Is there any way to achieve this?.

Comment: you will find your answer here http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/

Answer (score 0):

An Android project can't really fit into a .jar file, unless you just wanna use the compiled java files, which you would certainly have done it via a normal Java library project instead of a Android Library Project in first place.

Android Library Projects are packaged into **aar** files. Read more about it here: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/aar-format  and it is automatically handled by Gradle builds and late Android Maven scripts...this last one used to use a '**apklib**' format which has been deprecated to be replaced by **aar** format. You can read more about it here: https://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/ApkLib

Answer (score 0):

I've done this before.

But, due to my requirements, i only needed implementation (no android specific resources). Although you can still include Android actual code (if the project you're going to use it in is also an Android project in which you can load the SDK which includes the classes you're exporting in the jar)

Now the **.jar** file that is automatically generated in the **bin** folder, will **not allow** you to do this because it includes all the Android's project resources (which is not understood in the Jar format). Therefore, you must **exclude** all **except** the **src** folder. Note :  Make sure you also exclude the files in the root folder of the project (i.e, AndroidManifest.xml, etc .. )

In **Eclipse** : Project properties -> Export -> Jar -> (Include only src folder)

If you're project library includes native code ( NDK ), there is a few other workaround that you need to do to get it to work. If this is the case, comment below, i'll help you out.

Cheers